# Access is denied when building Blazor app

Tags: .net-core, blazor

I managed to get the Blazor tutorial working
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/aspnet/blazor-tutorial/intro

However, after making some modifications there seems to be some problems witch copying a file. I have tried to run powershell as admin but it did not help

```
PS D:\ragges\programmering\git\dotnet\blazorTest\BlazorApp> dotnet watch run
watch : Started
Building...
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4965,5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "D:\ragges\programmering\git\dotnet\blazorTest\BlazorApp\obj\Debug\net5.0\apphost.exe" to "bin\Debug\net5.0\BlazorApp.exe". Access to the path 'D:\ragges\programmering\git\dotnet\blazorTest\BlazorApp\bin\Debug\net5.0\BlazorApp.exe' is denied. [D:\ragges\programmering\git\dotnet\blazorTest\BlazorApp\BlazorApp.csproj]

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.

watch : Exited with error code 1

watch : Waiting for a file to change before restarting dotnet...
```

I managed to create a new app with
dotnet new blazorserver -o BlazorApp2 --no-https
but the old one will not work

Comment: Could it be that the old BlazorApp.exe is still running? Check in e.g. Task Manager.

Comment: Good idea, but I don't see any blazorapp in the task manager